# Passing a Rust variable to a C function that expects to be able to modify it

Tags: c, rust, ffi

I'm writing a safe Rust layer with which I can call functions from a C library in Rust. I've generated the unsafe bindings using [rust-bindgen](https://github.com/servo/rust-bindgen), but I'm getting a little confused on the differences between how Rust and C work with regards to passing pointers.

The C function looks like this:

```
bool imeGet(unsigned char address, int *value);
```

It reads an I2C sensor at `address`, stores the result in `value`, and returns `TRUE` on success.

Bindgen has the Rust function looking like this:

```rust
pub fn imeGet(address: ::std::os::raw::c_uchar,
              value: *mut ::std::os::raw::c_int) -> bool;
```

And my safe caller looks like this currently:

```rust
pub fn ime_get(addr: u8) -> i32 {
    let v: &mut i32 = 0;
    unsafe {
        imeGet(addr, v);
        *v
    }
}
```

This code doesn't compile because of the `= 0`. When I didn't have that, the compiler complained about `v` possibly not having been initialized. My intent is to handle the success within this function, and just return the `i32` value.

How do I handle the behavior of the `*mut c_int` argument? I tried to declare `v` as a reference and return its dereferenced value (above), but that doesn't work. I also tried to just return `v`, but I don't really want the return value to stay mutable.

I'm pretty new to Rust, but I do have a decent background in C, which may be my source of confusion.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> but I do have a decent background in C

The moral equivalent of your Rust code is:

```c
int *v = NULL;
imeGet(addr, v);
*v
```

This will have an error because the C code is likely going to dereference that `v` to store the value in, except you've passed in a NULL, so it's more likely to go boom.

You need to create storage for the value, then provide a reference to that storage to the function:

```rust
fn ime_get(addr: u8) -> i32 {
    let mut v = 0;
    unsafe { imeGet(addr, &mut v) };
    v
}
```

The solution for any pointer type uses [`ptr::null_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/ptr/fn.null_mut.html):

```rust
unsafe { 
    let mut v = std::ptr::null_mut();
    takes_a_pointer_pointer(addr, &mut v);
    v
}
```

The general solution for any type uses [`mem::MaybeUninit`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/union.MaybeUninit.html):

```rust
unsafe {
    let mut v = std::mem::MaybeUninit::uninit();
    takes_a_value_pointer(addr, v.as_mut_ptr());
    v.assume_init()
}
```

For completeness, you should be checking the return value:

```rust
fn ime_get(addr: u8) -> Option<i32> {
    let mut v = 0;
    let success = unsafe { imeGet(addr, &mut v) };

    if success {
        Some(v)
    } else {
        None
    }
}
```

> the differences between how Rust and C work with regards to passing pointers.

There really aren't any, at this level.

Comment: Ack, dunno what I was thinking. Thanks!