# Provide `char **` argument to C function from Rust?

Tags: rust

I've got a C function that (simplified) looks like this:

```
static char buffer[13];

void get_string(const char **s) {
    sprintf(buffer, "Hello World!");
    *s = buffer;
}
```

I've declared it in Rust:

```
extern pub fn get_string(s: *mut *const c_char);
```

But I can't figure out the required incantation to call it, and convert the result to a Rust string. Everything I've tried either fails to compile, or causes a SEGV.

Any pointers?

Comment: [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=578f81f8830f7d6cb7dc3224ddfe6ab0&version=stable&mode=debug) should work, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24145823/how-do-i-convert-a-c-string-into-a-rust-string-and-back-via-ffi/24148033#24148033) answer for more information, maybe a duplicate ?

Comment: The linked question _returns_ a string, rather than using an out param, so I couldn't see how to adapt it. Your example seems to work; post it as an answer, maybe?

Comment: *Everything I've tried* — would you care to show some of those attempts?

Comment: Combining [Passing a Rust variable to a C function that expects to be able to modify it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42727935/155423) and [How do I convert a C string into a Rust string and back via FFI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24145823/155423) should be sufficient.

Comment: Yeah; they're _not_ sufficient. There's a difference between a `char **` argument and a `char *` return value, and also between an `int *` argument and ` char **` argument. I'm new to Rust; I have _no idea_ how to combine them.

Comment: "would you care to show some of those attempts?"; no, because they're not relevant. It's a simple question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, [`char` in Rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/primitive.char.html) is **not** the equivalent to a [`char` in C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#Basic_types):

> The `char` type represents a single character. More specifically, since 'character' isn't a well-defined concept in Unicode, `char` is a '[Unicode scalar value](http://www.unicode.org/glossary/#unicode_scalar_value)', which is similar to, but not the same as, a '[Unicode code point](http://www.unicode.org/glossary/#code_point)'.

In Rust you may use `u8` or `i8` depending in the operating system. You can use [`std::os::raw::c_char`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/os/raw/type.c_char.html) for this:

> Equivalent to C's `char` type.
>
> [C's `char` type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#Basic_types) is completely unlike [Rust's `char` type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/primitive.char.html); while Rust's type represents a unicode scalar value, C's `char` type is just an ordinary integer. This type will always be either `i8` or `u8`, as the type is defined as being one byte long.
>
> C chars are most commonly used to make C strings. Unlike Rust, where the length of a string is included alongside the string, C strings mark the end of a string with the character `'\0'`. See [`CStr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/ffi/struct.CStr.html) for more information.

First, we need a variable, which can be passed to the function:

```
let mut ptr: *const c_char = std::mem::uninitialized();
```

To pass it as `*mut` you simply can use a reference:

```
get_string(&mut ptr);
```

Now use the `*const c_char` for creating a [`CStr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/ffi/struct.CStr.html):

```
let c_str = CStr::from_ptr(ptr);
```

For converting it to a `String` you can choose:

```
c_str.to_string_lossy().to_string()
```

or

```
c_str().to_str().unwrap().to_string()
```

However, you shouldn't use `String` if you don't really need to. In most scenarios, a [`Cow<str>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html) fulfills the needs. It can be obtained with `c_str.to_string_lossy()`:

> If the contents of the `CStr` are valid UTF-8 data, this function will return a `Cow::Borrowed([&str])` with the the corresponding `[&str]` slice. Otherwise, it will replace any invalid UTF-8 sequences with `U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER` and return a `Cow::[Owned](String)` with the result.

You can see this in action on the [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=578f81f8830f7d6cb7dc3224ddfe6ab0&version=stable&mode=debug). [This Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=be54841578572384bd721194c044d963&version=stable&mode=debug) shows the usage with `to_string_lossy()`.

Comment: `std::mem::uninitialized()` is deprecated for now, use `mem::MaybeUninit` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Combine [Passing a Rust variable to a C function that expects to be able to modify it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42727935/155423)

```
unsafe { 
    let mut c_buf = std::ptr::null();
    get_string(&mut c_buf);
}
```

With [How do I convert a C string into a Rust string and back via FFI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24145823/155423):

```
extern crate libc;

use libc::c_char;
use std::ffi::CStr;
use std::str;

extern "C" {
    fn get_string(s: *mut *const c_char);
}

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        let mut c_buf = std::ptr::null();
        get_string(&mut c_buf);
        let c_str = CStr::from_ptr(c_buf);
        let str_slice: &str = c_str.to_str().unwrap();
        let str_buf: String = str_slice.to_owned(); // if necessary
    };
}
```