# How do I pass arguments by reference when calling Rust from C++?

Tags: c++, rust

I am trying to do a very simple test to see how I can call Rust functions from C/C++.

My C++ code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

extern "C" {

int32_t add_one(int32_t x);

} // extern "C"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int32_t x = 14;
    cout << x << endl;
    cout << add_one(x) << endl;
    cout << x << endl;
}
```

My Rust code:

```rust
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn add_one(x: i32) -> i32 {
    x + 1
}
```

Compiled to a library, this gives a `.dll` and a `.d` file to compile against:

```
g++ main.c libc_rust.a -o output.exe
```

As I expect, this gives me `14 15 14`.

How do I make my Rust function not return an integer but instead take `x` as a reference and increase the value of `x` by 1, giving the output `14 15 15`?

If I write `pub extern "C" fn add_one(x: i32) -> ()` using parenthesis, that means the return value is unit. I don't know what "unit" is exactly, but seems to do the job for `void` in this situation.

Comment: Have you tried passing by pointer?

Comment: kinda I used &mut, and mut : &i32 but i don't know why but it didn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```rust
#[no_mangle]
// See note below
pub extern "C" fn add_one(x: &mut i32) {
    *x += 1;
}
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

extern "C" {

void add_one(int32_t *x);

} // extern "C"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int32_t x = 14;
    cout << x << endl;
    add_one(&x);
    cout << x << endl;
    cout << x << endl;
}
```

By using `&mut` in the function argument, we are requiring that the caller provides a valid reference. Among other things, that requires that:

- It not be NULL
- It be properly aligned
- It doesn't alias any other value.

It's up to the caller of the function to ensure these conditions, otherwise it will cause undefined behavior.

See also:

- [The Rust FFI Omnibus](http://jakegoulding.com/rust-ffi-omnibus/)
- [Passing a Rust variable to a C function that expects to be able to modify it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42727935/155423)
- [How do I pass a reference to mutable data in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23574416/155423)
- [What's the difference between placing "mut" before a variable name and after the ":"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28587698/155423)